# Vim typescript files doesn't open first time

Tags: terminal, filetype

I have a strange issue with `TypeScript` or `.ts` files in terminal vim. I tried opening it from `NERDTree` or `Control+P`.

It finds the file but for some strange reason after I hit the `Enter` key from `Control P` it doesn't open, I tried hitting `Enter` multiple times it only adds lines to the status line at the bottom.

However if I press `Ctrl + C` it terminates and brings up the `.ts` content. It only happened **recently** but I don't know what I've done to cause this. It used to open fine, even though it took more than a second or two.

I am using:

OS: Mac OSX Sierra

Vim in the terminal

I have the following plugins:

- vim-typescript
- tsuquyomi

All I remember doing recently was `npm install -g typescript tsc`.

Comment: `Its only happened recently but I don't know what I've done to cause this` That how you'll know: [how do i debug my vimrc](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: @statox I'll give it a crack and see thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So following fronm @statox suggestion to a previous debug thread.

I used the following command to trace my issue:

1. Ensure it wasn't something in my `.vimrc`. FAILED - so it was my something in my `.vimrc`
2. Use the following command to trace the `.vimrc` file

**Command**: `vim --noplugin -D`

3. It detected error with the `Tsuquyomi` plugin.
4. I don't know how I fixed bit but I re-downloaded the plugin and added the appropriate `ts` checker.

**It seems to have fixed my current issue.**

I suspect it was me doing the `npm install -g typescript and tsc` recently which would have overwritten something or add new binary.